# Take year and month from date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 3 columns, the first column is date (date data type).I want to filter results from years or months or both. I found this:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate='2015-12-11';
```

But how can I select for example, everything with year 2015 or year 2015 and month 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter results using MySQL's built in [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE 
YEAR(OrderDate) = 2015 AND 
MONTH(OrderDate) = 11;
```

You can also use these to return additional results:

```
SELECT YEAR(OrderDate) AS OrderYear FROM Orders
```

Or you can sort your results:

```
SELECT * AS OrderYear FROM Orders ORDER BY YEAR(OrderDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Year` and `Month` function

```
SELECT year(OrderDate) as `Year`,month(OrderDate) as `Month`
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderDate='2015-12-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you use date ranges:

```
select o.*
from Orders o
where OrderDate >= '2015-11-01' and
      OrderDate < '2015-12-01';
```

Using ranges allows the database engine to use an index on `Orders(OrderDate)`.  This can make the query run much faster (if such an index is available).

The use of functions generally prevents indexes from being used.