# select where year less than 2014

Tags: mysql

I want to select all posts from 2014 or less. How can I do this?

```
SELECT id, fotos, cover, titulo, descricao, data, link_key FROM posts where `date` < '2014'
```

data is datetime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql take year and month from date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229581/sql-take-year-and-month-from-date)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggestion:

```
where date < '2014-01-01'
```

Keeping the comparison simple ensures that indexes and partitions can be used for the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extract function.

```
SELECT id,
       fotos,
       cover,
       titulo,
       descricao,
       data,
       link_key
FROM posts
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) < 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `YEAR` function:

```
SELECT id,
       fotos,
       cover,
       titulo,
       descricao,
       data,
       link_key
FROM posts
WHERE YEAR(date) < 2014
```